# Purpose of Input Resistor On AC/DC Converter?

Tags: power-supply, power, ac, dc, converter

I am currently in the process of sourcing an AC/DC converter module for a project I am working on. I am thinking about using the PSK-3D-5 120VAC to 5VDC converter, which gives the following example schematic in its datasheet:

[image]

I am wondering what the purpose of the 12 ohm input resistor is in this circuit?

The device is a fairly large monolithic unit, so why is the resistor not built in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mainly there to make an official deisgn that can pass the EMI and EMC requirements.

The module takes a large inrush current when mains voltage is connected to it. The 12 ohm resistor limits this inrush current.

In the next diagram in the datasheet which describes a circuit for better EMI/EMC, the resistor is also larger, 33 ohms.

It may have a slight effect on reducing noise, ripple and harmonics it causes towards mains network.

As the requirements are different in different countries and also different countries have different mains voltage, it makes more sense to produce a single module and let users connect it to mains based on local EMI/EMC requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to use the module without the resistor?